# how to save record when the value is null in cakephp?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I want to sava the record but in the for loop the next id is null, how can i save the records with this condition, the loop will be stop when it find null and save the previous records.

```
 foreach($record['ProductPlan'] as $value=>$key)

{
 $ProductsUser = array('product_plan_id'=>$key,'user_node_id'=>$userNodeId, 'is_active'=>1);
                            $this->$model->UserNode->ProductPlansUserNode->create();
                            $this->$model->UserNode->ProductPlansUserNode->save($ProductsUser);

                        }
```

and the error is Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'product_plan_id' cannot be null
and in the array

```
   '2'
array(
'product_plan_id' => '2',
'user_node_id' => '26',
'is_active' => (int) 1
)
'3'
array(
'product_plan_id' => '3',
'user_node_id' => '26',
'is_active' => (int) 1
)
'' // This is null how can i save previous records before null?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confused between $value and $key, it should be used vice versa

You need to add a check for empty or null array before inserting in to table
Try this

```
 foreach($record['ProductPlan'] as $value=>$key){
   If($key){
   $ProductsUser = array('product_plan_id'=>$key,'user_node_id'=>$userNodeId, 'is_active'=>1);
   $this->$model->UserNode->ProductPlansUserNode->create();
   $this->$model->UserNode->ProductPlansUserNode->save($ProductsUser);  
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

As your error says ,

`Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'product_plan_id' cannot be null`

You have to alter this field to allow `null` in db to save null records. And if you want db to descide it self a unique key for that column make it `AUTO_INCREMENT`. So it will take the next key if you pass `null` for that column.

Answer (score 3):

Just use normal if . Here is the sample code:

```
 foreach ($record['ProductPlan'] as $value => $key) {
    if (isset($key) && $key) {
       $ProductsUser = array('product_plan_id' => $key, 'user_node_id' => $userNodeId, 'is_active' => 1);
       $this->$model->UserNode->ProductPlansUserNode->create();
       $this->$model->UserNode->ProductPlansUserNode->save($ProductsUser);
    }
 }
```

Comment: i dont want to insert null value in table, how can i do this?

Comment: if the product_plan_id column is AUTO_INCREMENT , it will get incremented automatically after you passing value null, NULL will not be inserted in the database

Comment: primary key is product_plan_user_node_id and the foreign keys are product_plan_id and user_node_id, the foreign key and primary key in my table is not null. I want to add data without null value.

Comment: when i change product_plan_id is null in table it insert the record with null value, i dont' want to do insert record with null value, only those records whose product_plan_id is not null. hope you understand.